# Google Analytics - Tracking Nonstandard Query Strings

Tags: google-analytics, tags, query-string

I am trying to track query strings in Google Analytics, but I have a problem.  I have too many variables to fit in the "normal set" provided by Google.  They allow you to set utm_source, utm_medium, utm_term, utm_content and utm_campaign.  I need another one, let's call it my_qs.

So my URL would look like:

http://example.com?utm_source=stack-exchange&utm_medium=web&utm_term=google-analytics&utm_content=nonstandard-query-strings&utm_campaign=answers&my_qs=gotmike

I can obviously find reports for all the standard query strings in Google Analytics, but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to run reports on these other variables that show up in the URLs.

I looked into Custom Variables, and they seem like something that is set by the Google Analytics code, not by the query string in the URL.

Maybe the answer is to write some javascript to grab my query string and store it as a Custom Variable in Google Analytics?

I read several articles about creating Custom Variables based on data stored on your website, but I'd really like to provide a simple URL link back to my website and get the data from the query string based on a user clicking that link.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: First off have you considered upgrading your GA to Universal? I presume you are using classic as you refer to custom variables. With UA you can set your query parameter into a custom dimension, which is similar to a custom variable. You also get 20 slots to use compared to just 5 custom variables.

Comment: I am using UA.  I'm not sure Custom Variables are the answer, that's all I was able to uncover in searching.  How do Custom Dimensions work and how do you set them up to be set by query string?

Comment: Custom Dimensions (CDs) work similarly to Custom Variables, and they are analogous to the standard dimensions already available in GA. You can customize your CDs , using Javascript, to any dimension you want. In your case, you would need to write the logic to grab the query parameter and to place that in a variable that would be sent in as a CD.

Comment: so do you have a reference that shows how to write this logic to grab the query parameter?  can it be done in google tag manager?

Comment: Definitely, it can be done in GTM, I'll post up an answer if you are indeed using GTM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GTM, then you can grab the query parameter quite easily by creating your own variable to grab your qp. The variable would look something like this:

[image]

You could then provide "my_qs parameter" as a value for your Custom Dimension in your tags. Make sure you have already defined and configured this in your GA account first.